# The constructor of an inner class of a superclass is undefined if there is argument in the super-constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, subclass, superclass

I have a class `A`, and `A_sub` is an inner class of `A`.

```
public class A {

    protected class A_sub { 
        int A_sub_x = 1;
        A_sub parent;
    
        A_sub(A_sub obj_A_sub) {
            System.out.println("Constructor A.A_sub");
            parent = obj_A_sub;
        }
    }

    public A() {
        System.out.println("Constructor A");
    }

}
```

Then I have a class `Main` (which extends `A`) with a method `main`. `Main` also have an inner class `A_sub` (which extends `A.A_sub`). But I got an error message at the line of `super()` saying "The constructor A.A_sub() is undefined". How can I got it solved?

```
class Main extends A{

    public Main() {
    }

    private class A_sub extends A.A_sub{ 
        int A_sub_z;

        A_sub(A_sub obj_A_sub) {
            super();
            System.out.println("Constructor Main.A_sub");
            A_sub_z = 3;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Main obj = new Main();
        A_sub obj_sub = obj.new A_sub(null);

        System.out.println(obj_sub.A_sub_x);
        System.out.println(obj_sub.A_sub_z);

    }
}
```

Comment: Because there is no default constructor in parent class, Hence the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The really is no constructor as `A$A_sub.A_sub()` - the constructor you have takes an `A_sub` argument. One way to solve this is pass `Main$A_sub.A_sub`'s argument to its parent's constructor:

```java
class Main extends A{

    private class A_sub extends A.A_sub{ 
        int A_sub_z;

        A_sub(A_sub obj_A_sub) {
            super(obj_A_sub);
            // Here-^
            System.out.println("Constructor Main.A_sub");
            A_sub_z = 3;
        }
    }

    // The rest of Main's constructors and methods have been snipped for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create an empty constructor in class A_sub

So, inner class A_sub should be

```
protected class A_sub {
        int A_sub_x = 1;
        A_sub parent;

        A_sub(A_sub obj_A_sub) {
            System.out.println("Constructor A.A_sub");
            parent = obj_A_sub;
        }

        public A_sub() {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the class `Main.A_sub` extends `A.A_sub` and it has non-default constructor you have to pass the required argument

```
    private class A_sub extends A.A_sub {

        A_sub(A_sub obj_A_sub) {
            super(null); // Pass the required argument
            //....
        }
    }
```